# Computing $\int_{0}^{1} x^2 \sin(2\pi nx)\sin(2\pi mx) \,dx$

Tags: integration

I would like to know if there is any easy way or known formula to compute the following integral. For $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, for $n \neq m$, $$ \int_{0}^{1} x^2 \sin(2\pi nx)\sin(2\pi mx) \,dx$$ I tried various graphs for $n\ne m$, and it seems the answer is $0$. That's why I thought there might easy way to deal with this. Thanks.

Comment: You could try first Werner formulas to get rid of the product of sines, and than following with integration by parts to remove the x^2

Comment: Try $z=2\pi x-\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

$$2\sin a\sin b=\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)$$

and by parts

$$\int x^2\cos(px)\,dx=\frac1px^2\sin(px)-\frac1p\int 2x\sin(px)dx
\\=\frac1px^2\sin(px)+\frac1{p^2} 2x\cos(px)dx-\frac1{p^2}\int 2\cos(px)dx.$$

Comment: I think last term inside integral should be $2\cos(px)$

Comment: @Believer: right, thanks.